# How to extract tags from a remote git repository in node js without having git installed in the application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I am developing an application in nodejs. I need to extract tags from our project repository. Is there a way to do this without having git installed on the server where the application is runnning? Can this be done?

I do not want to install git or clone the repo on the server. I also need the solution to include authentication.

Comment: Look into nodegit

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=git

Comment: Can somebody please provide a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of trial and error, I found the solution to this. The node package [Isomorphic Git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-git) came to the rescue.
Here is the working code:

```
var git = require("isomorphic-git");
let info = await git.getRemoteInfo({
        url: gitHubRepoUrl,
        token: accessToken,
        oauth2format: 'gitlab'
    }); 
    let result = Object.keys(info.refs.tags);
```

Comment: You are right, however isomorphic git is also based on the .git directory but the getRemoteInfo method is however not. As per the docs =>This is a rare command that doesn't require an fs, dir, or even gitdir argument. It just communicates to a remote git server.

Answer (score 0):

A working example of the same, considering that the source code has the .git folder , using the git-repo-info package would be:

```
var getRepoInfo = require('git-repo-info');

var info = getRepoInfo();
console.log(info.tag); //
```

Comment: Very bad answer. [`git-repo-info`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-repo-info) requires `git` which the OP doesn't want to install. It also requires local clone which the OP doesn't want to do. The OP wants something to work with a remote repo without cloning it.

Comment: Hi @phd. I did not asked to clone the repo, I just asked to keep the .git directory with the source code itself. I tried exploring the packages suggested in the comments above. But all including git-repo-info could only fetch the repo info via the .git directory and were unable to do the same using the repo url. Plus I am not sure if it requires git to be installed.

Comment: Having `.git` means clone (clone without checkout). The OP wants to work with **remote** repo, not local. Ok, doesn't require `git`, I admit, sorry.

Comment: I was suggesting a hack of keeping the .git with the source when taking the most updated code to the server. And considering the case when the OP would not have git installed on the server, he/she would have to always take the most updated code to the server by some or the other method.

Comment: Please try out my answer and select it as a solution for this question if it works.